# Question regarding convergence in distribution

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Q: Let $X$ be a continous r.v and let
$F_X(t)=
  \begin{cases}
    0 & , & t<0 \\
    t^n & , & 0\le t < 1 \\
    1 & , & t \ge 1
  \end{cases}
$

Let $Y_n=\sqrt{n}(1-X)$, prove that $Y_n\xrightarrow{d} 0$.

I'm interested in the direct proof **only**, meaning to show that $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}F_{Y_n}=F_0$.
Here are my attempts so far:

$F_{Y_n}(t)=P(\sqrt{n}(1-X)\le t)=P(X\ge 1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})=$
$1-F_X(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})=1-
\begin{cases}
  0 & , & 1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} < 0 \\
  (1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})^n & , & 0 \le 1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} < 1\\
  1 & , & 1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} \ge 1
\end{cases}=$
$
\begin{cases}
  1 & , & t > \sqrt{n} \\
  1-(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})^n & , & 0 < t \le \sqrt{n} \\
  0 & , & t \le 0
\end{cases}$

The thing i'm not sure about is that the range of $t$ is dependant on n, so what happens when $n\to\infty$?
(1) Does it mean that the inequality $t>\sqrt{n}$ is a false statement, therefore the first case is eliminated?
(2) Does the case $0<t\le \sqrt{n}$ just simplifies to $t > 0$?
(3) Do I over complicate things?

I've never came across that problem before, and it seems a bit odd. If both answers to (1),(2) are "yes", then I could easily derive that $F_{Y_n}(t)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}F_0(t)$.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: I think it would be better to write $Y_n=\sqrt{n}(1-X)$, $Y_n\xrightarrow{d} 0$, etc, since you are talking of different $Y$'s for each $n$

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you fix $t>0$ and let $n$ be large enough (i.e. greater than $t^2)$ you have $0<t<\sqrt{n}$ so you can write:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_Y(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=1-0=1$$

So the answer to your questions is:

1. For fixed $t$ you have $t>\sqrt{n}$ is false if $n$ is large enough (and your limit only depends on large enough values of $n$)
2. See the note above
3. You seem to look only at the expression itself, and forget about the limit

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question, from my understanding. I know what you stated, in fact that's one of the cases I came across for $F_Y(t)$. I would appreciate a more clear answers to qustions (1),(2).
Thanks :)

Comment: Take for example $t=10$. Then for $n>100$ you have $0<t<\sqrt{n}$, so can you see what happens when you take the limit of $F_Y(t)$ when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: thanks for that. I think that you missed the part where I sayed that if both answers to questions (1),(2) are "yes" then I can show the required limit. I just edited that part to be more clear. If I understand correctly, then you say that both answers are "yes", right?

Comment: Technically,I wouldn't say that $t>\sqrt{n}$ is false. I would just say that the limit does not care of what happens if $\sqrt{n}<t$. Also, it's not very clear what you mean by "simplifies" in "$0<t\le \sqrt{n}$ just simplifies to $t > 0$". The statements are somewhat right, but lack mathematical rigor.

Comment: what I ment by "simplifies" is that after taking the limit on $F_{Y_n}$, the case of $0 < t \le \sqrt{n}$ will produce a result (which happens to be 1) that holds when $0<t$

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Thank you for the help and all of your replies, they are very much appreciated